# Twitter REST API 1.1: Search Tweets by geolocation coordinates returns wrong / inaccurate results?

Tags: json, api, rest, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter REST API ver. 1.1, specifically "GET search/tweets" to get tweets around a location, I have submitted the following 3 parameters:

```
NSDictionary* params = @{@"q" : @"%20",
                         @"geocode" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%fmi",
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.latitude],
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.longitude],
                                       radius],
                         @"count" : @"30"};
```

- q (required): since I want 30 tweets around a coordinate so I submitted "%20", which is essentially a space
- geocode: My current coordinate. 6 digits after decimal point. Within a 5 mile radius.
- count: I want 30 tweets returned.

But the JSON I got in return seems to be confusing and even wrong, there are basically 3 problems with the JSON response:

#### 1. The Tweets returned do not seem to be really nearby.

I have tried to tweet on my device with geolocation marked and then run the code. I could never see my own tweet. What's more, when I look into the tweets returned, it's not clear that all of then are really in the specified range. All of them appears to be from the area, but some of them are probably farther than 5 miles away, and some of them I cannot tell where they are tweeted, which brings me to my next point:

#### 2. Not all tweets returned have geo info, like coordinates, etc

If all these tweets are returned after querying by geo location, then how come some of them do not even come with coordinates? Some of them have

> "geo": null

AND

> "coordinates": null

The ones that have geo information are even more confusing, which brings me to my next point:

#### 3. The JSON data is probably not formatted correctly.

In the JSON data returned of those tweets who have geo / coordinate info, I am seeing things like the following data:

```
   "geo":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
           47.7676977,
           -122.2264493
        ]
     },
     "coordinates":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
           -122.2264493,
           47.7676977
        ]
     },
```

I mean, WUT?

Problem 1: It has "coordinates" and "coordinates" inside of "geo", aren't they the same thing?
Problem 2: The 2 "coordinates" have values with long and lat **IN REVERSE**!!! In my case, apparently "47.7676977, -122.2264493" is right, but what the...??

I hope someone with experience of integrating with Twitter API can walk me through these problems with "GET search/tweets". All I am trying to do is to get tweets around a certain coordinates. Please share your experience of solving similar problems, or let me know if this is a known problem on Twitter's side.

Helps are appreciated!